# Electromagnetic compatibility (EMC) standard

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, emc, standard

I have been working on a battery fast charger of around 500W. I have been wondering if active power factor correction (PFC) is necessary and have seen people mention a European standard EN 61000-3-2. This standard lists maximum current harmonics of all devices with input power over 75W.

My question is: Is there a law in Europe that restricts the production/sales of devices that do not comply with this standard?

I have measured the input current of my Lenovo laptop charger listed at 170W and have seen that the current is terribly distorted, which made me question if passing the standard is required for my device.

Comment: you are not allowed to sell such an item as a consumer product without CE marking. That marking implies EMC which in your case implies PFC. However, since you put on the marking by your own responsibility, many product get away with falsely labeling CE although being noncompliant. this can leed to fines and more though. the required power factor is not sooo sinusoidal actually so i guess your lenovo psu is probably fine

Comment: @tobalt Thank you! You said everything I wanted to know. The Lenovo psu current shape looks more like it's on the "false labeling" than "probably fine" side, though

Comment: @tobalt Could you please give me your take on this current waveform (Lenovo psu input)? Pictures: https://imgur.com/CZ7SMWa , https://imgur.com/3prUvvz

Comment: Not very "great" ... Very "noisy" and not very "clear" ! Seems with no conducted "EMI" protection.

Comment: Maybe also a malfunction ?

Comment: Order a low cost "genuine original PSU" from a webshop which is hidden somewhere in  a jungle or a 10 million population Asian city. If you are lucky you get a device which outputs the right voltage, but nothing is done to fulfill European or US EMC requirements - no filters, no shielding, no active PFC. Except there's all possible stamps which assure "this device is not only perfect for consumers, it's also good enough even for marine-, hospital or aviation applications. The stamps are not worth more than the ink they contain.

Comment: @Ljaban that looks like (bad) active PFC to me. you clearly see the underlying sine shape and then there is an excess of current near the peaks.. usually one needs a certain mediocre power factor at certain higher load. power factor can be worse at lighter loads. mainly it doesn't draw *all* of its current in a single peak only...

Answer (score 3):

Measure it? The standard will list a defined test-method and limits.

The CE mark means: "I promise that my product complies with all the relevant laws and requirements" There are lots of standards, and you need to make an assessment for each one. It sounds awful, and it kinda is, but take deep breath and read the "EU blue guide"

Falsely labelling the product has been mentioned, but that is a terrible idea. It's a huge risk; If discovered you will go bankrupt as you need to recall all your products and it will be illegal to sell and distribute it. If it somehow caused damage you'll be fined and might even go to prison.

So this is a big deal. All of the mayor brands will have dedicated test-labs, and as any distributors are also responsible (yep) large brand shops may conduct their own testing (or require documentation from a reputable test-lab) to make sure that the products they sell complies with the law. If it doesn't comply *they* need to do the recall, but *you* will be bankrupt, so *they* can't get their money back.

I find it extremely unlikely that Leonvo has gotten it wrong. They don't falsely label.

Comment: >>> I find it extremely unlikely that Leonvo has gotten it wrong. They don't falsely label.     $$$$  Gotta agree with THAT!!!!   No way, no how are they not testing properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Measure what, though? I didn't question if my device complies with the standard, but if it even needs to. And you answered that.

As for Lenovo, I expected they wouldn't falsely label as well, which is what made me think that complying with the standard isn't necessary. I remain confused after seeing the current waveform (pictures in the comments under the post).

Comment: @Ljaban I was by no means suggesting that you falsely label CE due to reasons mentioned here. +1 I was merely stating that such products exist, mainly from China... most of the offbrand stuff available on Amazon/ Alibaba etc. *because* it is practically possible. This *is* illegal however there is rather little care and enforcement around this issue. If you have a competitor, this will be an easy invitation to them to sue you off the market forever.

Comment: @tobalt No worries there! I was just confused about the meaning behind the label. Wasn't at any point thinking about falsely labeling myself.